# Como verificar se uma string está contida em outra em C?

Tags: c, string, funções

Eu tenho duas variáveis:

```
char s1[20];
char s2[20];
```

Eu irei pegar o *input* do usuário das duas variáveis, e depois disto, eu preciso verificar se `s1` está contida em `s2`, até mesmo, uma parte só dela. Para isto eu irei utilizar uma função chamada `esta_contido()` que irá fazer esta verificação.

#### Exemplo:

```
    s1 = "algoritmo"; 
    s2 = "ritmo";
    esta_contido(); retorna 4 --> pois ele retorna a primeira posição do caractere em que está contido.
```

#### Meu código:

```
char s1[20];
char s2[20];

void esta_contido() {

    printf("Digite uma string : ");
    scanf("%s",&s1);

    printf("Digite outra string : ");
    scanf("%s",&s2);


    if (strstr(s1, s2) != NULL) { 

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if(s2[i] == s1[i]) {
            i = 20;
            printf("s2 : %s", &s2);
        }
    }

    }


}


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    esta_contido();


}
```

Na parte do `if` com `for` estou verificando se `s1` e `s2` tem alguma parte igual, se tiverem ele vai pro for, para verificar quais palavras são iguais, após isto ele da um `output` pro usuário as palavras que são iguais. Nisto eu já consegui algum progresso, mas eu preciso dar `output` pro usuário não as letras, mas sim a posição inicial em que está contido a *string*.

Comment: if (strstr(s1, s2) != NULL) {
    // contem
}

Comment: Obrigado pelo código, o que falta é como eu posso saber em que posição inicial está a letra em que está contida. Usando um for para percorrer toda a string, funcionaria ?

Comment: A `strstr` fornece essa informação de maneira um pouco menos direta. Acho que com um pouco de aritmética de ponteiros se resgata exatamente essa informação que você precisa

Comment: Sou novo em C, e ponteiros ainda é algo um pouco complexo para mim, poderia me explicar um pouco mais de como posso fazer esta checagem ? Eu olhei na função strchr() mas não estou conseguindo reproduzir o que eu quero, eu estou tentando agora converter char para int para poder mostrar o indice da posição dele, mas sem sucesso também.

Comment: Você quer só obter a posição ou quer fazer um algoritmo que calcule a posição? Não tem que saber nada de ponteiro neste caso.

Comment: Eu só quero obter a primeira posição em que está contida a string. Assim como no exemplo acima em que eu dei, se o usuário entrar por exemplo com a string "algoritmo" e depois  em outra string "ritmo", ele irá retornar a primeira posição em que está contida, neste caso, posição 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como já existe uma função pronta que pega uma parte da *string*, bastante fazer uma subtração de onde achou a segunda *substring*  na primeira *string*.

Há alguns outros erros neste código e ele nem compila.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char s1[20];
    char s2[20];
    printf("Digite uma string : ");
    scanf("%s", s1);
    printf("Digite outra string : ");
    scanf("%s", s2);
    printf("%ld", strstr(s1, s2) - s1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/PZg0af). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/agkzubwv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/IndexOf.c).

Pode ser que deseja verificar se `strstr(s1, s2)` é nulo para informar que não existe uma *string* dentro da outra.

Comment: Muito obrigado @bigown como sempre você ajudou rapidamente no que eu precisava, quando vi sua resposta, já sabia que iria me ajudar e realmente me ajudou. Era disto que eu precisava, só faltava esta parte para o código ficar pronto do jeito que eu queria. Só me perdoe a ignorância, o que seria %ld ?

Comment: É `long int`, dependendo do compilador ele terá um retorno deste tipo.

Comment: Ah tudo bem, muito obrigado pela explicação.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main(){
    char S1[100], S2[100];
    int i,j,c=0;
    printf("digite a string S1\n");
    gets(S1);
    printf("digite a string S2\n");
    gets(S2);
    if(strlen(S1)<=strlen(S2)){
        printf("S2 nao he substring de S1\n");
    }else{
        for(i=0;i<strlen(S1);i++){
            if(S2[0]==S1[i]){
                for(j=0;j<strlen(S2)-1;j++){
                    if(S2[j]==S1[i++])
                        c++;
                }
            }
            if(c==strlen(S2)){
                break;
        }
    }
    if(c==strlen(S2))
        printf("S2 he string de S1\n");
    else
        printf("S2 nao he string de s1\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Fiz diferente:

```
internal class Program
{
    static bool VerificaString(string s1, string s2)
    {
        int cont = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s1[i]==s2[0])
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < s2.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (s1[i]==s2[j])
                    {
                        cont++;
                        i++;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        if (cont == s2.Length)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s1, s2;
        bool resultado;

        Console.Write("\nDigite a primeira string: ");
        s1 = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("\nDigite a segunda string: ");
        s2 = Console.ReadLine();

        resultado = VerificaString(s1, s2);

        if (resultado == true)
            Console.WriteLine("\nA string '{0}' foi encontrada na string '{1}'!", s2, s1);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nA string '{0}' não foi encontrada na string '{1}'!", s2, s1);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```