# Como ler cada char de uma string, para saber se uma está contida na outra, em C?

Tags: c, string

Bom dia, boa tarde, boa noite.
Estou tentando fazer um enunciado do meu curso de programação em C que pede para fazer um código que verifica se uma string2 está contida em uma string1, utilizando aritmética de ponteiros, tentei de diversas formas realizar este exercício, mas a única forma que encontrei de realiza-lo é a partir do método que irei mandar aqui, só que ao executar o código eu consigo verificar que está contida somente as primeiras letras da string1, por exemplo: se digito "brasil" para a primeira string e digito "bra" pra a segunda, ele detecta que está contida, mas se digito "brasil" para a primeira e "sil" para a segunda, ele não detecta que está contido, gostaria de saber como resolver este problema. Desde já agradeço, aguardo resposta. Obs.: O enunciado está como comentário no código, bem embaixo das bibliotecas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
18) Elabora uma função que receba duas strings como parâmetros e
verifique se a segunda string está dentro da primeira. Para isso, utilize
apenas aritmética de ponteiros.
*/

void verifica(const char* ptr1,const char* ptr2) {
  int l=0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(ptr1); i++) {
   if (ptr1[i]==ptr2[i]) {
     l++;
    }//if
  }//for

  if (l == strlen(ptr2)) {
    printf("Está contida!! \n");
  }else{
    printf("Não está contida!! \n");
  }//ifelse
}//verifica

int main (){
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
  char str1[21], str2[21];
  char *ptr[2] = {str1, str2};


  for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("Digite a %dº palavra de até 20 caracteres: ", i + 1);
    fgets(ptr[i], 21, stdin);
    ptr[i][strcspn(ptr[i],"\n")]='\0';
    setbuf(stdin,NULL);
  }//for

  verifica(ptr[0],ptr[1]);


return 0;
}//main
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá. Entendendo a questão, pude perceber que o problema está na verificação de contido. Vamos lá:

Pense comigo, i vai de 0 a strlen(ptr1) -1. Correto?

Vamos usar os mesmos inputs do erro:

(brasil, sil)

i na posição 0:
string1 == b  e string2 == s -> logo o l não incrementa

i na posição 1:
string1 == r  e string2 == i -> logo o l não incrementa

i na posição 2:
string1 == a  e string2 == l -> logo o l não incrementa

O primeiro problema é que nesse caso nunca vai verificar. O segundo problema é que
após isso, o i vai continuar incrementando, mesmo que não exista mais letras na string2, e vai começar a comparar o resto das letras da string1 (sil) com lixo da string2.

[Como verificar se uma string está contida em outra em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213806/como-verificar-se-uma-string-est%C3%A1-contida-em-outra-em-c)

esse topico pode te ajudar bastante nessa questão. É basicamente a mesma dúvida.

Comment: vlw, muito obrigado mesmo!!!